# Docusign REST API MERGE FIELD - SALESFORCE

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Im trying to prefill my document with salesforcse Lead Name, however i cant accomplish it, the signHereTabs, and dateSignedTab is showing but the 
texttabs dont get any data,

The REST API Documentation https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/CustomTabs/CustomTabs/create/#request
says: that the row field is the "Specifies the row number in a Salesforce table that the merge field value corresponds to." but if i pass the salesforce record id im getting the error:

DocuSign Response{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
  "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. int value expected for parameter: mergeField.row"
}

This is my json request:

{
    "emailSubject": "Agreement", 
    "emailBlurb": "MSTSolutions is sending you this request for your electronic signature and enter or update confidential payment information.Please review and electronically sign by following the link below.",
    "templateId": "42a4815d-f8ac-4972-b1ea-2e1534324658",
    "envelopeIdStamping": "false", 
    "templateRoles":  [{
        "roleName": "Signer 1",
        "name": "TEST TEST",
        "email": "xxx@xxxx.com",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [{
                "xPosition": "25",
                "yPosition": "50",
                "documentId": "1",
                "pageNumber": "1"
            }],
            "dateSignedTabs": [{
                "name": "Date Signed",
                "xPosition": "25",
                "yPosition": "100",
                "documentId": "1",
                "pageNumber": "1"
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "tabLabel": "LeadFirstName",
                "xPosition": "25",
                "yPosition": "200",
                "documentId": "1",
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "mergeField": {
                    "configurationType":"Salesforce",
                    "path":"Lead",
                    "row":"00Q29000003fI13",
                    "writeback":"true",
                    "allowSenderToEdit":"true",
                }
            }]
        }
    }], 
"status": "sent"
}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fairly sure the error is is how your path is configured. Try this:

```
"path": "Lead.FirstName"
```

and then remove the "Row" line

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes' create endpoint you can pass in the lead/opportunity/account Ids via the "Custom Fields" section. This will set all custom Salesforce fields you have defined in the template (relating to the SFIDs you provide) without having to set each tab one by one.

```
   "customFields":{  
      "textCustomFields":[  
         {  
            "value":"0060n00000DIvfNAAT",
            "name":"Opportunity",
            "configurationType":"salesforce"
         }
      ]
   }
```

Note the textCustomFields is enclosed in a customFields block (which matches the published API) and most importantly, the configuration type must be set to "salesforce" and the Name must be "Opportunity" (etc) without the ##SF prefix which appears in a lot of examples on the web (for the SOAP api). By examining the 'GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/custom_fields' endpoint you can see that the API is automatically afixing the ##SF prefix and modifying the Value to include the record name:

```
{
  "textCustomFields": [
    {
      "fieldId": "10140751586",
      "name": "##SFOpportunity",
      "show": "false",
      "required": "false",
      "value": "0060n00000DIvfNAAT~Test Opp Lisa Simpson"
    }
}
```